# Like '__LINE__', is there any standard macro in C/C++ which prints thread name or ID?

Tags: c++, c, macros, posix, qnx

I am using some functions across multiple threads in my application written in C++ in QNX IDE. Sometimes while analyzing the logs, it is difficult to find the thread who has called it. Though I can use [gettid](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/660/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.qnx.doc.neutrino.lib_ref%2Ftopic%2Fg%2Fgettid.html) or [pthread_getname_np](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.3.2/neutrino/lib_ref/p/pthread_getname_np.html) in logs, still looking for a standard macro like  [__LINE__](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.4.0/dinkum_en/c99/preproc.html) .

Even if it is not supported by QNX, I would like to know if any other OS/Compiler/standard has it.

Comment: That id is run time specific so there won't be a standard macro similar to \_\_LINE\_\_ which is known at compile.

Comment: Referring "*standard*": `gettid()` isn't Standard C, nor `pthread_getname_np()` is POSIX. Use `pthread_self()`.

Comment: You can use `pthread_self()` to get the `pthread_t` instance, which is standard. Alternatively, use a wrapper structure that contains a `pthread_t` member and an ID (e.g. the address of the structure variable), and you can pass that address to the start routine when creating the thread.

Comment: I think I made a silly mistake and overlooked this simple fact that thread Id is not known at pre-processing state. Thanks all for pointing it out!

Answer (score 7):

The line number of a line is known at compile time, even by the preprocessor, so the preprocessor can substitute `__LINE__` with the actual line number.

But the thread-id is only known at run-time, and furthermore it will be different for different executions of the same statement. So it cannot possibly be the value of a macro.

You precisely need to use a run-time call like the ones you mention in order to discover the thread id. You may well need a platform-specific mechanism, since neither Posix nor C define a portable mechanism to obtain a thread id. As of C++11, you can use [`std::this_thread::get_id()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/get_id) to obtain a unique, printable [thread id](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/id).

Comment: It's worth noting that there is **no** portable way of getting the unique integral thread ID of a particular thread in a particular process, even during run-time.  Some OSes provide a way, but none of those methods are POSIX-compliant.

Comment: @tonysdg: C++ does have a portable way of getting a unique printable thread identifier (std::thread::id). I don't know of a C or Posix equivalent, but this question is (also) tagged C++.

Answer (score 4):

In C++11, check out [std::this_thread::get_id](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/this_thread/get_id/).
It has a method of generating human-readable strings, if you need them. There is no standard macro for this behavior, as it's rather run-time dependent.

Answer (score 2):

No, because unlike `__LINE__` thread IDs are not statically determined at compile time.  Moreover threads are not part of the C or C++ languages, so the compiler is not aware of them - you'd have to make a call to determine the thread ID in any case (though C++ 11 supports threads through the standard library).

If you really must, this can always be faked with a macro:

```
#define __THREAD__ gettid()
```

or in C++ 11:

```
#define __THREAD__ std::this_thread::get_id()
```

Or whatever system dependent means of obtaining a thread or process ID is provided by the target - it is not entirely portable, although C++11 holds out the best possibility for portability once support is ubiquitous.

But to do so hides the overhead of the function call and makes it look like a literal constant, I'm not sure I'd advocate *misleading* code.  Moreover the use of `__` is reserved, so it is further misleading.

Answer (score 1):

If you are satisfied with an identifying handle for a thread, then the same value that is returned in the first parameter to `pthread_create()` can also be obtained by the running thread by calling [`pthread_self()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_self.html).<sub>This was pointed out in a comment by Chrono Kitsune</sub>

If you are only creating a static set of threads and you want to associate each with an ordinal value, you could use a `static` counter and a thread local variable. At the creation of each thread, atomically read and increment the counter, and set the thread local variable to the read value.